# Is there any way to reliably send youtube videos trough email?

Tags: email, html-email

My boss insists on embedding a youtube video in some of our automated emails (to trial users, not spam email) but afaik very few email clients will show iframes. Is there any way to embed youtube videos so that they will show in a majority of clients, or maybe another video service we could use? (tho i doubt the service would make the difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html5 for video but it is not widely supported. Here is a support [chart](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3529/).

By using an image that looks like a Youtube player (for example) that hyperlinks to the web hosted video is a good alternate. Most subscribers will forgive the 'not playing in email' as long as the hyperlinked page serves the desired video up.

Comment: That's what I thought. I've convinced the marketing manager to either change the emails or use images that link to the video or a custom page that has the videos embedded. Thanks.